# Small service for hashing and validating passwords, using PBKDF2

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography, .net-core

As part of a larger authentication/authorization system, I've developed a small .NET Core 3.0 service for hashing passwords using [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) (with a salt) and validating passwords against a stored hash/salt, for use as part of a larger authentication/authorization system.

Code organization:

- `IPasswordService` is the main interface used by the larger system.
- `PasswordService` is the implementation, the heart of this body of code.
- `KeyDerivationParameters` and `CryptoRng` are used when configuring and loading the service (ideally through a DI container).
- `ICryptoRng` is used as an interface to stub out when unit testing `PasswordService`.
- `ValueTypes` contains domain-specific types wrapping primitives, using the [ValueOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/ValueOf/) library.
- `HashedPassword` is a simple wrapper encapsulating both a hash and a salt.
- `PasswordServiceTests` contains my unit tests.

My main concerns (though all feedback is welcome):

- Security - making sure there's no obvious attack I'm missing. I should note that I only chose PBKDF2 because it has an implementation in .NET; argon and bcrypt are only available in C# through third-party libraries in various states of maintenance. I also intend on using a larger iteration count in practice than the 10,000 iterations specified in the tests; I wanted to keep the unit tests fast.
- Tests - I only have four unit tests for the `PasswordService`, and I'm not confident that they provide enough of a safety net.
- The use of ValueOf to create meaningful domain-specific types instead of using primitives everywhere. In Haskell, using newtypes for this sort of thing is common, but I'm curious what C# developers think about it.

The code is broken up into eight files across two projects; it's available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/DylanSp/AuthSystemPasswordService/tree/45060af4ad7f931caba0bc55280440f34dcec246), as well as below. The projects are .NET Core 3.0, using

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
</PropertyGroup>
```

in the .csproj files to enable C# 8's nullable reference types.

**IPasswordService.cs**

```
namespace AuthSystemPasswordService.Interfaces
{
    public interface IPasswordService
    {
        HashedPassword GeneratePasswordHashAndSalt(PlaintextPassword password);
        bool CheckIfPasswordMatchesHash(PlaintextPassword password, HashedPassword hash);
    }
}
```

**ICryptoRng.cs**

```
namespace AuthSystemPasswordService.Interfaces
{
    public interface ICryptoRng
    {
        byte[] GetRandomBytes(int numBytes);
    }
}
```

**ValueTypes.cs**

```
using ValueOf;

namespace AuthSystemPasswordService
{
    public class PlaintextPassword : ValueOf<string, PlaintextPassword>
    {
    }

    public class Base64Hash : ValueOf<string, Base64Hash>
    {
    }

    public class Base64Salt : ValueOf<string, Base64Salt>
    {
    }

    public class IterationCount : ValueOf<int, IterationCount>
    {
    }

    public class SaltLength : ValueOf<int, SaltLength>
    {
    }

    public class KeyLength : ValueOf<int, KeyLength>
    {
    }
}
```

**HashedPassword.cs**

```
namespace AuthSystemPasswordService
{
    public struct HashedPassword
    {
        public Base64Hash Base64PasswordHash { get; }
        public Base64Salt Base64Salt { get; }

        public HashedPassword(Base64Hash passwordHash, Base64Salt salt)
        {
            Base64PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            Base64Salt = salt;
        }
    }
}
```

**KeyDerivationParameters.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation;

namespace AuthSystemPasswordService
{
    public struct KeyDerivationParameters
    {
        public KeyDerivationPrf DerivationFunction { get; }

        public IterationCount IterationCount { get; }

        public SaltLength SaltLength { get; }

        public KeyLength KeyLength { get; }

        public KeyDerivationParameters(KeyDerivationPrf derivationFunction, IterationCount iterationCount,
            SaltLength saltLength, KeyLength keyLength)
        {
            DerivationFunction = derivationFunction;
            IterationCount = iterationCount;
            SaltLength = saltLength;
            KeyLength = keyLength;
        }
    }
}
```

**CryptoRng.cs**

```
using AuthSystemPasswordService.Interfaces;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace AuthSystemPasswordService.Services
{
    public class CryptoRng : ICryptoRng
    {
        private RandomNumberGenerator Generator { get; }

        public CryptoRng()
        {
            Generator = RandomNumberGenerator.Create();
        }

        public byte[] GetRandomBytes(int numBytes)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[numBytes];
            Generator.GetBytes(bytes);
            return bytes;
        }
    }
}
```

**PasswordService**

```
using AuthSystemPasswordService.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace AuthSystemPasswordService.Services
{
    public class PasswordService : IPasswordService
    {
        private KeyDerivationParameters Parameters { get; }
        private ICryptoRng Rng { get; }

        public PasswordService(KeyDerivationParameters parameters, ICryptoRng rng)
        {
            Parameters = parameters;
            Rng = rng;
        }

        public HashedPassword GeneratePasswordHashAndSalt(PlaintextPassword password)
        {
            var saltBytes = Rng.GetRandomBytes(Parameters.SaltLength.Value);
            var salt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);

            var hashBytes = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(password.Value, saltBytes, Parameters.DerivationFunction,
                Parameters.IterationCount.Value, Parameters.KeyLength.Value);
            var hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

            return new HashedPassword(Base64Hash.From(hash), Base64Salt.From(salt));
        }

        public bool CheckIfPasswordMatchesHash(PlaintextPassword password, HashedPassword hash)
        {
            var passwordHash = KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(password.Value, Convert.FromBase64String(hash.Base64Salt.Value), Parameters.DerivationFunction,
                Parameters.IterationCount.Value, Parameters.KeyLength.Value);
            return passwordHash.SequenceEqual(Convert.FromBase64String(hash.Base64PasswordHash.Value));
        }
    }
}
```

**PasswordServiceTests**

```
using AuthSystemPasswordService.Interfaces;
using AuthSystemPasswordService.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using NSubstitute;
using System;

namespace AuthSystemPasswordService.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PasswordServiceTests
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("UnitTest")]
        public void GenerateHashAndSalt_ReturnsSalt_WithNumberOfBytesEqualToSaltLengthParameter()
        {
            // Arrange
            var iterationCount = 10_000;
            var saltLength = 16;
            var keyLength = 64;
            var parameters = new KeyDerivationParameters(KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA512,
                IterationCount.From(iterationCount), SaltLength.From(saltLength), KeyLength.From(keyLength));

            var rng = Substitute.For<ICryptoRng>();
            rng.GetRandomBytes(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(args => new byte[args.Arg<int>()]);

            var service = new PasswordService(parameters, rng);

            // Act
            var hash = service.GeneratePasswordHashAndSalt(PlaintextPassword.From("somePassword"));

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(saltLength, Convert.FromBase64String(hash.Base64Salt.Value).Length);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("UnitTest")]
        public void GenerateHashAndSalt_ReturnsHash_WithNumberOfBytesEqualToKeyLengthParameter()
        {
            // Arrange
            var iterationCount = 10_000;
            var saltLength = 16;
            var keyLength = 64;
            var parameters = new KeyDerivationParameters(KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA512,
                IterationCount.From(iterationCount), SaltLength.From(saltLength), KeyLength.From(keyLength));

            var rng = Substitute.For<ICryptoRng>();
            rng.GetRandomBytes(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(args => new byte[args.Arg<int>()]);

            var service = new PasswordService(parameters, rng);

            // Act
            var hash = service.GeneratePasswordHashAndSalt(PlaintextPassword.From("somePassword"));

            // Assert
            Assert.AreEqual(keyLength, Convert.FromBase64String(hash.Base64PasswordHash.Value).Length);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("UnitTest")]
        public void GenerateHashAndSalt_ThenCheckingSamePassword_ReturnsTrue()
        {
            // Arrange
            var iterationCount = 10_000;
            var saltLength = 16;
            var keyLength = 64;
            var parameters = new KeyDerivationParameters(KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA512,
                IterationCount.From(iterationCount), SaltLength.From(saltLength), KeyLength.From(keyLength));

            var rng = Substitute.For<ICryptoRng>();
            rng.GetRandomBytes(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(args => new byte[args.Arg<int>()]);

            var service = new PasswordService(parameters, rng);

            var password = PlaintextPassword.From("somePass");

            // Act
            var hash = service.GeneratePasswordHashAndSalt(password);
            var checkResult = service.CheckIfPasswordMatchesHash(password, hash);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsTrue(checkResult);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [TestCategory("UnitTest")]
        public void GenerateHashAndSalt_ThenCheckingOtherPassword_ReturnsFalse()
        {
            // Arrange
            var iterationCount = 10_000;
            var saltLength = 16;
            var keyLength = 64;
            var parameters = new KeyDerivationParameters(KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA512,
                IterationCount.From(iterationCount), SaltLength.From(saltLength), KeyLength.From(keyLength));

            var rng = Substitute.For<ICryptoRng>();
            rng.GetRandomBytes(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(args => new byte[args.Arg<int>()]);

            var service = new PasswordService(parameters, rng);

            var password = PlaintextPassword.From("somePass");
            var otherPass = PlaintextPassword.From("otherPass");

            // Act
            var hash = service.GeneratePasswordHashAndSalt(password);
            var checkResult = service.CheckIfPasswordMatchesHash(otherPass, hash);

            // Assert
            Assert.IsFalse(checkResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly use https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net instead of PBKDF2.

Comment: What's your goal? I see a lot of code, but in the end it just performs PBKDF2 and base 64 encoding? Wrapper classes should not be a goal in itself.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Ultimately, the goal is to provide a mockable, easy-to-use interface for the rest of my authentication/authorization system to use that has a bit more type safety than throwing byte[]'s around.

Answer (score 1):

One potential security issue, as mentioned in [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/104911/95905) to a similar piece of code, is that the use of `SequenceEqual()` in `CheckIfPasswordMatchesHash()` may open this up to timing attacks.